# Bibliography with Metadata:

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am constructing a bibliography of as much of the prior research in a field I am working in. I would like to use `BibTeX` to print the citation in the `pdf`, and then I would like to add the details of the paper after the citation. Only then would I like to print the next citation. For example:

> [1] Jahan M. Dawlaty and Yunquing Chen. Measurement of the optical absorption of graphene in the terahertz. Applied Physics Letters, 2008.
>
> Research Group: Cornell
>
> Pump Wavelength: 500 nm.
>
> Probe Wavelenth: 7 microns.
>
> Relaxation Time: 50 fs.
>
> [2] Paul George and Dmitry Vekslar, Measurement of Ultrafast Carrier Dynamics in Graphene. Applied Physics Letters, 2009.

. . . and so on.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: You could (ab)use the `note` field in the bib-file I suppose, putting the extra info there, optionally with some linebreaks etc.

Comment: You might use BibLaTeX+Biber's customisable data model to add fields to your .bib like RESEARCHGROUP={Cornell} or PW={500} etc. which can then be formatted like any other field in a biblatex style designed for exactly the format you need. If you can use biblatex+biber, it would be possible for someone to show how to do this, I am sure.

Comment: Depends on the style you use.  You could tweak the style to use the `annote` field, which was designed for producing annotated bibliographies (though it is not used by the standard styles).  In general, however, your job will probably be much easier if you use `biblatex`.

Comment: I could easily transfer to biblatex+biber, if that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

With `biblatex` you can use the field `addendum`, which is similar to `note`, but always printed at the end of the bibliography entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dawlaty,
  author={Jahan M. Dawlaty and Yunquing Chen},
  title={Measurement of the optical absorption of graphene in the terahertz},
  journal={Applied Physics Letters},
  year={2008},
  addendum={\par
    Research Group: Cornell \\
    Pump Wavelength: 500 nm. \\
    Probe Wavelenth: 7 microns. \\
    Relaxation Time: 50 fs.}}

@article{george,
  author={Paul George and Dmitry Vekslar},
  title={Measurement of Ultrafast Carrier Dynamics in Graphene},
  journal={Applied Physics Letters},
  year={2009}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% to remove the addendum (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208441)
% in the case that you want to use the same .bib file elsewhere without them
%\AtEveryBibitem{%
%  \clearfield{addendum}%
%}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For normal BibTeX, you could (ab)use the `note` field in the bib-file. This only works if the `note` is typeset last of course, and I don't know if that always is the case. Hence, this may not be a solution at all, though it works for the example you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dawlaty,
  author={Jahan M. Dawlaty and Yunquing Chen},
  title={Measurement of the optical absorption of graphene in the terahertz},
  journal={Applied Physics Letters},
  year={2008},
  note={\par
    Research Group: Cornell \\
    Pump Wavelength: 500 nm. \\
    Probe Wavelenth: 7 microns. \\
    Relaxation Time: 50 fs.}}

@article{george,
  author={Paul George and Dmitry Vekslar},
  title={Measurement of Ultrafast Carrier Dynamics in Graphene},
  journal={Applied Physics Letters},
  year={2009}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would definitely work, but if I wanted to use the .bib to write another paper, I would have to remove piles of notes. This isn't an insurmountable difficulty, though the work/reward ratio is increasing.