# Suppress the 'note' field using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using `biblatex` to handle my references, I prefer the `numeric-comp` style:

```
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=10,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    natbib=true,
    firstinits=true,
    hyperref,
    backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

this lets me hide the fields I don't want to appear in the bibliography, such as the url and isbn.

I also want to hide the 'note' field but `note=false` doesn't work.

How do I hide the note? It seems odd that `biblatex` gives the options to hide fields but not the note, I can't think why.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{note}%
}
```

See also [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076), section "Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields".

Comment: Thanks for the link. As can be seen in the instructions there, the proper command when you use e.g. `\footcite` is `\AtEveryCitekey` instead of `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279916/174840