# Exclude note and addendum from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, custom-bib

I am using biblatex to print bibliographies. Although, it is handy to have `adendum` and `note` fields in bib entries, I wonder if there is a way to remove them from the output. I tried to use `adendum=false` and `note=false`, but they don't work.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
    @Article{bibkey,
      Title                    = {Some title},
      Author                   = {John Joe},

      Addendum                 = {some addendum},
      note                     = {some notes},
      Doi                      = {blah blah},
      Month                    = {Feb},
      Number                   = {2},
      Pages                    = {950-955},
      Volume                   = {62},

      Journal                  = {J. LaTeX},
      Keywords                 = {Some keyword},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[%
 backend=bibtex8,% or bibtex8
 style=numeric,%
 sorting=ydnt,% sorted by year, descending
 eprint = false,
 url=false,
 ]{biblatex}


% Recommended for biblatex

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

some text \cite{bibkey}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Suppress the 'note' field using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208441/35864), [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\clearfield`

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}\clearfield{addendum}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{note}\clearfield{addendum}}
```

the second line also removes the field from citations.

---

If you use Biber you can even remove these fields before they are processed

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=addendum, null]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    } 
  }
}
```

this can have the advantage that any code that might normally throw TeX off is not processed and thus rendered harmless.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bibkey,
  Title       = {Some title},
  Author      = {John Joe},
  Addendum    = {some addendum},
  note        = {some notes},
  Volume      = {62},
  Journal     = {J. LaTeX},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
 backend=biber,
 style=numeric,
 ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=addendum, null]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    } 
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{bibkey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```