# Only include certain fields in BibLaTeX bibliography

Tags: biblatex, mendeley

I am using `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` to make my bibliography but it automatically includes fields such as ISSN, DOI, URL etc that I don't want to display as which fields are included varies so much between journal articles when I produce my .bib file by exporting from Mendeley. I could go through and delete all the fields I do not want from the .bib file but this would be extremely time consuming for the number of citations in a thesis! Is there a way (the simpler the better - I am new to LaTeX!) to customise which fields are included in the bibliography (either in LaTeX or in Mendeley)?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Haye you tried `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}` ?

Comment: Thanks so much @Fran - that worked, problem solved! :)

Comment: @Fran Answer or close?

Comment: As the question currently stands it would be pretty much a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/35864, do you agree? Note though, that only a few select fields can be toggled off via a package option (pretty much only DOI, ISBN/ISSN, URL, `eprint`, ...). For other fields more work is needed (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279871/35864)

Comment: @cfr  with moewe warning about  another fields, not much left to say. Vote to close.